# ACF Auto hyper link for specific Textarea field type

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, field, advanced-custom-fields

I added this below code in theme functions

`add_filter( 'the_content', 'make_clickable',     12 );`

This made all text url within "the_content" auto hyperlink. But not one of my advanced custom field.

Again, I tried this for my custom field by adding it in theme functions and using acf filter

```
add_filter('load_field/name=downloadable_links', 'my_acf_load_field', 'make_clickable', 12);
```

But this just made my custom field url contents invisible and not hyperlink.

This is my custom field downloadable_links . Field type:  Textarea. I am also using repeater with this.
I have several links within each of this field and I want them all to be auto hyperlink without making it manually each time.

This is my custom field front-end output code.

```
<div><?php echo do_shortcode("[acf field='file_sharing_name']"); ?><? $folios = get_field('game_download'); if($folios){foreach( $folios as $f ){?><div class="wrap"><div class="file-zone-title"><? if($f){ ?><span><?= $f['file_sharing_name']?></span><? } ?></div><div class="file-download-links"><?= $f['downloadable_links']?></div><div class="clear"></div></div><?}} ?><div class="clear"></div></div>
```

Would be very kind if someone can suggest me how I can make it work. As I am unable to make it work with above information. First time asking for suggestion here. So, I am sorry if I made any mistake in my request. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by myself and with a help from another topics. :) after doing a bit more research.

I followed this tips on here:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103957/how-to-explode-a-textarea-field-and-echo-each-line-separately-wrapped-with-html

and modified my functions output code for my custom field into this and it is working fine with hyperlink as I wanted.

```
    $lines = explode("\n", get_field('downloadable_links')); // or use PHP PHP_EOL constant
if ( !empty($lines) ) {
  echo '<ul>';
  foreach ( $lines as $line) {
    echo '<li>'. '<a href=' . $line . '>' . trim( $line ) . '</a>' . '</li>';
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}
```

Good luck - if anyone else need this. :)